# Female protagonist that is sick in one reality and well in another

Tags: story-identification, novel, parallel-universe

I read a few books in a series of novels with a female protagonist.  She was either severely injured or very ill in 'our world', but she was able to travel to another dimension.  They referred to the places where you could move back and forth from 'our world' to the other as 'thin places.'

I believe it was written by a female author, and  I remember really enjoying it, but cannot remember the name of the series, the author or any of the titles! :(

Please help me find this book!

Comment: Welcome to the community! Excellent question! Please take some time to read the [faq], if you've not already. Where have you tried looking already? When did you read it?

Comment: Could you be referring to the Phaze series by Piers Anthony?

Comment: There's a female character in Tad Williams' _Otherland_ series who is bed-bound in the _real_ world, but when in the _Otherland_ is able to walk.  [Possible Spoiler] I think her name was Francis?  I'm also fairly sure there was some confusion about her gender within the story.  Either way, Tad Williams is definitely male, so I guess this isn't the answer you're looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

This reminded me of an audio book series my wife was listening to from the library. It took a bit to track it down.

The series by Mary Hoffman is called [*Stravaganza*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stravaganza_%28series%29), and is about a number of characters from England who travel back and forth between an alternate version of Renaissance Italy. The first book was called *City of Masks*.

One of the main characters was recovering from cancer in our world. The discrepancies are that the ill character is male, and the mechanism for travelling to the alternate universe is by use of a talisman. I don't remember if there was any mention of 'thin places' in the use of the talismans.

There are various strong female characters, so it may be possible that this is the series you are thinking of. If not, then perhaps it will be of use to other searchers. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

It might have been the [Second Chronicles of Thomas Covenant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Thomas_Covenant#The_Second_Chronicles_of_Thomas_Covenant) by [Stephen Donaldson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_R._Donaldson).

Comment: Same problem as with the other answer: there is no mention of "thin places"; you can't just move back and forth.

Comment: Doesn't really match the description, no?

Comment: Well, Stephen Donaldson may be one of the first authors to use that sort of plot-line.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Barbed Coil" by J V Jones? Your description reminded me of that.

Comment: How so? We need a little more description.

Comment: Can you provide details that suggest similarities?

Comment: This book seems to be about a _ring_ that transports to another world, not "thin places". Are there specific details you remember that much up with that?

Comment: The similarities were that it was a female protagonist and in the "real" world she had crippling migraines or something similar. In the fantasy world she had some sort of special powers.
Also, the author is female.

No more details than that I'm afraid, it's been quite a few years since I read it. The description brought it to mind though.